# Rust Actix TLS error -> stream error: request parse error: invalid Header provided

Tags: docker, ssl, rust, https, actix-web

I try to make a Rust Actix TLS web server.

Project layout

```
.
├── .env
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── certs
│   ├── cert.pem
│   └── key.pem
└── src
    ├── api_error.rs
    ├── handlers.rs
    └── main.rs
```

.env

```
RUST_LOG=debug
PORT=443
CERTIFICATE_PATH=certs/cert.pem
PRIVATE_KEY_PATH=certs/key.pem
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "https-test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
actix-web = { version = "4.3.1", features = ["openssl"] }
openssl = { version = "0.10.54", features = ["v110"], optional = true }
anyhow = "1.0.72"
log = "0.4.19"
env_logger = "0.10.0"
dotenvy = "0.15.7"
```

main.rs

```
mod api_error;
mod handlers;

use anyhow::{anyhow, Result};
use log::info;

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    dotenvy::dotenv()?;
    env_logger::init();
    info!("Starting server");

    let port = std::env::var("PORT")?.parse::<u16>()?;

    let server = actix_web::HttpServer::new(|| {
        actix_web::App::new()
            .wrap(actix_web::middleware::Logger::default())
            .service(actix_web::web::scope("/api/v1").configure(handlers::config_app))
    });

    let server = server.bind_openssl(("0.0.0.0", port), {
        info!("Using TLS");
        let mut builder = openssl::ssl::SslAcceptor::mozilla_intermediate(openssl::ssl::SslMethod::tls())
                .unwrap();
        let private_key_path = std::env::var("PRIVATE_KEY_PATH")?;
        let certificate_path = std::env::var("CERTIFICATE_PATH")?;
        builder
            .set_private_key_file(private_key_path, openssl::ssl::SslFiletype::PEM)
            .unwrap();
        builder
            .set_certificate_chain_file(certificate_path)
            .unwrap();
        builder
    })?;

    server.run().await.map_err(|e| anyhow!(e))
}
```

handlers.rs

```
use crate::api_error::ApiError;

pub fn config_app(cfg: &mut actix_web::web::ServiceConfig) {
    cfg.service(actix_web::web::resource("/").route(actix_web::web::get().to(index)));
}

async fn index() -> Result<actix_web::HttpResponse, ApiError> {
    log::debug!("Hitting `index`");
    Ok(actix_web::HttpResponse::Ok().body("Hello world !"))
}
```

Note: the certificate is self-signed with a CA that I generated. I put the root CA in my system's trusted CA so I don't get the "Untrusted certificate" error in the browser every time.

When running the server, I get the expected logs:

```
$ cargo run --release
[INFO  https-test] Starting server
[INFO  actix_server::builder] starting 10 workers
[INFO  actix_server::server] Actix runtime found; starting in Actix runtime
```

Then on the browser, I go to `https://localhost/`, my browser can't connect to the server, in the logs I get:

```
[ERROR actix_http::h1::dispatcher] stream error: request parse error: invalid Header provided
[ERROR actix_http::h1::dispatcher] stream error: request parse error: invalid Header provided
[ERROR actix_http::h1::dispatcher] stream error: request parse error: invalid Header provided
[ERROR actix_http::h1::dispatcher] stream error: request parse error: invalid Header provided
[ERROR actix_http::h1::dispatcher] stream error: request parse error: invalid Header provided
[ERROR actix_http::h1::dispatcher] stream error: request parse error: invalid Header provided
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to the HTTP/1.1 parser detecting an invalid header in the request. This can happen due to various reasons, such as:

1. Misconfigured SSL/TLS settings
2. Incorrect client behavior (although browsers are unlikely to send malformed headers)
3. Interference from some proxy or firewall

Let's explore some troubleshooting steps:

#### Check SSL/TLS Configuration

Make sure your SSL/TLS certificates are properly loaded, and the path is correct. Double-check if you can use `openssl` CLI to inspect them:

```bash
openssl x509 -in certs/cert.pem -text -noout
openssl rsa -check -in certs/key.pem
```

#### Validate Environment Variables

Ensure that `CERTIFICATE_PATH` and `PRIVATE_KEY_PATH` environment variables are correctly loaded and pointing to the correct paths.

#### Examine Raw HTTP Traffic

You can use a tool like `tcpdump` or Wireshark to capture the raw packets between the client and server. This can provide further clues about what's wrong with the headers:

```bash
sudo tcpdump -i lo0 'port 443' -w capture.pcap
```

#### Try With a Different Client

Instead of a browser, try using `curl` to see if the error still persists. Make sure to use the `-k` flag to accept the self-signed certificate.

```bash
curl -k https://localhost:443/api/v1/
```

#### Increase Log Verbosity

Modify your `.env` file or directly set `RUST_LOG` to `trace` to get even more detailed logs. This can provide clues into what part of the request is causing the error.

#### Test Without SSL/TLS

Try running the server without SSL/TLS to see if the issue is actually related to SSL/TLS or something else. If it works fine without SSL, it's likely an issue with your SSL configuration.

Let me know which step gives you more information or if you have further questions.

Comment: The post itself doesn't contain the solution, but it helped me debugging. The problem was that, for a reason that is still to determine, the server was expecting HTTP traffic, and the browser sent HTTPS requests. The code I provided didn't contain a `feature` mechanism I implemented, I could choose between HTTP and HTTPS on compile time, I think this caused the issue. Thank you very much for your help !